# Недопустимые символы регулярного выражения java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, кириллица

Пытаюсь делить текст на слова, в split передаю регулярное выражение, которое по всей вероятности должно допускать все буквы кириллицы,латиницы и цифры. Сообщение от компилятора:
 Illegal character range near index 10
^[Р°-С?Р?-РЇС?Р?|a-zA-Z0-9]+$
Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

```
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(System.in, "Cp1251"))
    {
        Map<String, Long> map = Stream.of(reader.readLine().toLowerCase()
                         .split("^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+$"
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                          Collectors.counting()));

       map.entrySet().stream()
          .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByKey()))
          .limit(10)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException|PatternSyntaxException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: В какой кодировке у вас файлы?

Comment: скобок не хватает.

Comment: Попробуйте перевести в формат \U1234

Comment: И да, для кириллицы лучше юзать UTF-8. Нормально выводит.

Comment: Tsyklop - Да, собственно говоря без разницы какую кодировку использовать, проблема остается. Я попробовала все, конечно же) По поводу скобок, каких скобок???

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в настройках ОС, с регулярным выражением все в порядке. В среде код прекрасно компилируется, только при компиляции в командной строке возникают проблемы.